# Is it possible to debug GWT project server side code using GPE(server side code been packaged as a jar)

Tags: debugging, gwt, servlets, maven

I have a GWT application which i can debug the server side using GPE easy when the server and client located at same project, now i remove server side code and package it as jar, add it as project dependency, Seem there is no way to debug server side code anymore, Any ideas? By the way i'm using Maven to organize my project.
 Thanks

Edit: by debugging i mean it can stop at breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Eclipse, build path config, when you include the jar, you are also allowed to associate the source path for that jar. That source would then be traversable during debugging.

Your server side certainly used a number of libraries, where the dependency is specified thro Maven. Maven plugin for eclipse spontaneously pulls in the source when your debugging traverses thro a maven supplied library. Provided that the library supplier had been compliant to maven artefact directory structure.

You can also mavenise your jar. You simply place your jar, source, pom, etc into the maven artefact directory structure. And then in maven include that path as a repository. In fact, you can create a quick-and-dirty maven repo on google code doing it that way.